# TableViewer update value of column when value in another column has changed

Tags: swt, jface

I have a table with 2 columns both are ComboBox columns. When a user selects a value in column 1, I want to update the options available in the ComboBox for column 2.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Update the values in your data model and then call `TableViewer.update(object, null)` where `object` is data model object for the row (that is the value your content provider returns for the row). The `update` call will cause the `TableViewer` to ask the content provider for the values for the row again.

Comment: My scenario is something like this, column 1 is countries, and column 2 is cities in that country. When a user selects the country in column 1 from combobox, I want to update the list of cities in column 2. So in each cell in column 2, the combobox will have different contents.